# Risk Free Rate vs LIBOR

Tags: finance

Theoretically, in pricing derivatives, most textbooks refer to the risk-free rate. What is obtainable in practice? The risk-free rate or the LIBOR rate?

Answer (score 2):

Before 2007, LIBOR was commonly used for risk-free rate. It was a good proxy because it was quite close to the OIS rates. Since 2007, the LIBOR–OIS spread has spiked and became unstable. Therefore, LIBOR is no longer a good proxy for discounting. Nowadays, Banks usually use OIS for modelling.

Read the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overnight_indexed_swap) on OIS-LIBOR spread. John Hull has a very popular [paper](http://www-2.rotman.utoronto.ca/~hull/DownloadablePublications/LIBORvsOIS.pdf) on the subject.

Comment: John Hull said: "Most derivatives dealers now use interest rates  based on overnight indexed swap  (OIS) rates rather than LIBOR when valuing collateralized derivatives. For non-collateralized transactions, most dealers continue to use LIBOR rates for valuation."

Comment: I was actually concerned about adding a risk premium to the risk-free rate vs using a risk-free rate directly in fx futures pricing.

Comment: @AkinyinkaAkintunde If you add a risk premium, then it's not a risk-free rate anymore?

Comment: @Student T Yes, it will no longer be risk-free. but will that be appropriate in pricing forwards?

Comment: @AkinyinkaAkintunde I think you should start a new question, so other people can join (not just you and me)